# Floating label with CSS

Tags: html, css, formio

I have a generated form using **formIo** and a need to add some style to this form.

i want to make label floating up when i focus to the input, only with **CSS**

this is the generated html and my css that i use to reach this goal:

```css
.ff-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.ff-label,
.ff-input {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.ff-input {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: text;
}

.ff-input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}

.ff-label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

/*i need to add here :placeholder-shown to the input but i dont know how i do it*/

.ff-container:focus-within > div+label {
  cursor: text;
  max-width: 66.66%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: translate(0, 2.125rem) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="ff-container">
  <div class="ff-sub-container">
    <input type="text" class="ff-input" placeholder="Your name here ..">
  </div>
  <label class="ff-label">Name</label>
</div>
```

**PS**:if you need more information, please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a spin. when you focus the input the label appears next to the input.
Other than that your question lacked general direction and gave no desired visuals so you will need to tweak the rest of the code to fit your needs.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.form-control {
  width: 50%;
}
.form-control:focus + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div ref="element" class="form-group">
    <input  class="form-control" type="text" ref="input">
    <label class="col-form-label hidden">Test</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, the challenge that i have is to let the input inside the **DIV**, and when i focus to the input the label move

Comment: move where? adjust the top and left properties to move it. back and forth

Comment: move to top for instance, but look to my html, there is an input inside a div, and a div with a label inside another div

Comment: ok, sample updated. i see your html and it looked excessive this is cleaner. Do you have a specific reason for the extra div?

Comment: yes, i know its complicated, but i should let it like that

Comment: because i have a generated form, and it's generated like that, and i need to add some specific style